# Car race 3D object (not image) rotation in android

Tags: android

I want to develop a car race game in which I want to rotate car object (not image) in clockwise direction at the time of car selection. After that I want to change the car object color when user drag the screen to left, like image sliding in Android. I don't know about any type of 3rd party API which is used for gaming development to make it easier. I think that the rotating car must be an animation but As I search Android only supports the animations in the form of XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to OpenGL in Android, i think it's the only reasonable way for you to complete your task and to program any game in general. 
This link will help you start: http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/

Comment: Thanks Sir, but I wants to know that what is the actual animation format Android System supports...